# Group theory: How does binary operation define its associated set?

Tags: group-theory

I am trying to do a little reading in group theory.  An exercise in the book I am reading asks for a proof of:

If $(G,\circ)$ and $H(,\circ)$ are groups both associated with associative operation $\circ$, $G = H$.  And, therefore, the set of a group is defined by the given binary operation.

I haven't been able to find a proof.  I thought I might find a *reductio ad absurdum* by assuming that $G$ had at least one member not in $H$ (or vice versa) and derive some contradiction from that.  Haven't had any luck.  Anyone know how to prove this?

Comment: Subgroups are definitely a thing, and they are usually conidered to have the same operation. So this means we have to ask: What is the exact, formal definition your book has of "binary operation"? (And if it starts with "a function", then we need to ask what its definition of "function" is too.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first instinct was to say that this does not make sense because the same "binary operation" can be used for many groups, e.g. $+$ for $\mathbb{Z}\subseteq \mathbb{Q}\subseteq \mathbb{R}\subseteq \mathbb{C}$. However, the definition of a binary operation on a set $X$ is that it is a map $X\times X\to X$. A function is specified by the data of its domain, codomain, and "rule." So if two groups $G$ and $H$ have the same binary operation, their codomains align: $G=H$ as do the domains: $G\times G=H\times H$. In particular, $(G,\circ)=(H,\circ)$ as groups.

Comment: I don't understand what is there to prove here. Isn't it trivial? If it is the same set and same operation then it is obviously the same group. (of course same operation implies same identity and same inverses as well)

Comment: Yes I agree, if this exercise makes sense at all, then it is trivial. I can only speculate that the point of the exercise is to ensure that the student understands the definition of an operation.

Comment: I agree, also. With this interpretation the exercise is much too "nitpicky." Without this interpretation it is senseless.